# Loop all arguments in a shell script

Tags: shell-script

I've created a shell script but I don't know how to do a loop that prints the number of lines in every file you pass to the script as argument. So that the output would be something like this:

```
2 lines in hello.sh
33 lines in /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: why not just `wc -l "$@"`?

Comment: See also [Bash "for" loop without a "in foo bar..." part](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/417292)

Comment: Similar: [How to use arguments like $1 $2 ... in a for loop?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/314032)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a POSIX shell, you want a `for` loop here, looping over `"$@"` which contains the command line arguments:

```
for filename in "$@"; do
    lines=$(wc -l < "$filename")
    printf '%u lines in %s\n' "$lines" "$filename"
done
```

Using all the quotes is quite important. It allows you to pass filenames that contain spaces and other characters.

```
./my_script.sh /var/log/syslog "$HOME/My Dir with Spaces/a file with spaces.txt"
```

Comment: Note that `"$@"` is the default target for `for`, so `for filename; do` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to loop over the command line argument in a script or shell function, you may do

```
for thing do
    commands using "$thing"
done
```

or

```
for thing in "$@"; do
    commands using "$thing"
done
```

In this case, assuming filenames given on the command line do not contain literal newlines, there's no need to do an explicit shell loop for this:

```
wc -l -- "$@" | sed -E '$d;s/^[[:blank:]]*([[:digit:]]*)[[:blank:]]*(.*)/\1 lines in \2/'
```

This would take all the command line arguments and run `wc -l` on them all.

The output is parsed by `sed` which discards the last line containing the total number of lines in the given files (using `$d`).  The rest of the output from `wc -l` is transformed into the output that you want by capturing the number of lines and the filename and then inserting the string `lines in` in-between.

Running the script with my own `.vimrc`, `.profile` and `.mailrc` files will return

```
8 lines in .vimrc
8 lines in .profile
4 lines in .mailrc
```

Notice that `wc -l -- "$@"` will create output like

```
   8 .vimrc
   8 .profile
   4 .mailrc
  20 total
```

which may actually be enough for what you want, without the need for `sed`.

Comment: Note that the amount of space in between the number of lines and the file name varies with the `wc` implementation (POSIX only guarantees there will be at least one _blank_).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for all the editing! This means that one can not reliably capture initial blanks in the filename in the output from `wc -l` unless one knows exactly how many blanks it uses as the separator. I've changed it so that it eats up _all_ blanks, assuming the output will only be used for presentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "${@}"; do
    wc -l -- "${file}"
done
```

`#!/bin/bash` Program that will execute this script.

`${@}` Positional arguments. Arguments that you give to the script through command line.

`file` Variable that will iterate over the arguments given in `${@}`.

`wc -l -- "${file}"` External command that will print the number of lines in `${file}` (except when `${file}` is `-` in which case it will print the number of lines on its standard input).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using `while` and `shift`

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    printf '%u lines in %s\n' $(wc -l < "$1") "$1"
    shift
done
```